# How to protect memory of random size?

Tags: c, unix

I want to protect my heap memory of random size. I know there is a API:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
int mprotect(void *addr, size_t length, int prot);
```

But in most UNIX platforms, it requires the addr must be a multiple of the system page size. Additionally, because protections are set on whole pages, length is, in effect, rounded up to the next multiple of the system page size.

So I consider whether there is a method I can protect memory of random size, not limited as multiple of the system page size. For example:

```
char *p = malloc(10);
mprotect(p, 10, PROT_READ);
```

This will only protect 10 bytes, not the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. The reason for the limitation of whole pages is typically due to a hardware limitation; the MMU simply isn't checking accesses at the byte level.

One trick you can do is to allocate a whole page, and then align your "random" small block at the end of the page. Here's a very crude illustration:

```
 [ block of some large size, i.e. 4096 bytes ][next block, not allocated]
 [ this space is wasted ...         ][ small ][access here will fail!]
```

That will fail to protect accesses *before* the block's start, though.

Comment: :Another question, to allocate a memory whose begin address is page size aligned, I need to use mmap. But after using pmap command to check, I find the memory is not allocated in the heap of the process, but another region (In Solaris OS). So is there any method of allocating memory page aligned in heap?